# Mapping fetched data in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, fetch-api

I have problem with mapping fetched data in react.
I have these data, which I successfully fetch, but I have trouble, with mapping it to array.

```
    order_id: 9999,
    order_items: [
      {
        ean: 1234,
        name: 'LIV Aquafilter 2000',
        count: 1
      },
      {
        ean: 12345,
        name: 'Beko EWUE 7612CSXS0',
        count: 1
      }
    ]
```

There is my code, the data console log work perfectly, but another two just logs nothing

```
const fetchInvoiceData = useCallback(async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    setError(null);
    try {
      const response = await fetch("some_link");
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("error!");
      }

      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data);
      const transformedData = data.results.map((invoiceData) => {
        return {
          id: invoiceData.order_id,
          name: invoiceData.name,
        };
      });
      setListData(transformedData);
      console.log(listData);
      console.log(transformedData);
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error.message);
    }
    setIsLoading(false);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchInvoiceData();
  }, [fetchInvoiceData]);
```

Comment: What's `listData`? Are you trying to `console.log` a variable that doesn't exist? Although I see you're also mapping over `.results` even though your JSON only has `.order_items`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why calling react setState method doesn't mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-calling-react-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately)

Comment: @KelvinSchoofs listData is just useState array, the .results was the problem, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the `console.log(listData)` logs nothing is setting the state is [asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#why-is-setstate-giving-me-the-wrong-value).

And the reason the `console.log(transformedData);` logs nothing is because you need to use `data.order_items.map` instead of `data.results.map`